# Remove rows that contain False in a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I assume this is an easy fix and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have a data frame as such:

```
         index               c1       c2         c3
2015-03-07 01:27:05        False    False       True   
2015-03-07 01:27:10        False    False       True   
2015-03-07 01:27:15        False    False       False   
2015-03-07 01:27:20        False    False       True   
2015-03-07 01:27:25        False    False       False   
2015-03-07 01:27:30        False    False       True
```

I want to remove any rows that contain `False` in `c3`. `c3` is a `dtype=bool`. I'm consistently running into problems since it's a boolean and not a string/int/etc, I haven't handled that before.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: How are you handling the file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Pandas deals with [booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) in a really neat, straightforward manner:

```
df = df[df.c3]
```

This does the same thing but without creating a copy (making it faster):

```
df = df.loc[df.c3, :]
```

When you're filtering dataframes using `df[...]`, you often write some function that returns a boolean value (like `df.x > 2`).  But in this case, since the column is already a boolean, you can just put `df.c3` in on its own, which will get you all the rows that are `True`.

If you wanted to get the opposite (as the original title to your question implied), you could use `df[~df.c3]` or `df.loc[~df.c3, :]`, where the `~` inverts the booleans.

For more on boolean indexing in Pandas, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).  Thanks to @Mr_and_Mrs_D for the suggestion about `.loc`.

Comment: Not sure but this might have the problem of creating a copy - maybe `df = df.loc[df.c3, :]` would be faster for big dataframes?

Answer (score 16):

Well the question's title and the question itself are the exact opposite, but:

```
df = df[df['c3'] == True]  # df will have only rows with True in c3
```

Comment: This will calculate another boolean series with `df['c3'] == True` that is completely redundant - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37213642/281545

Answer (score 9):

## Solution

```
df.drop(df[df['c3'] == False].index, inplace=True)
```

This explicitly drops rows where `'c3'` is `False` and not just keeping rows that evaluate to `True`

Comment: Since `c3 is a dtype=bool` would not suffice to say `df[~df['c3']]`? This has also the disadvantage of calculating `~df['c3']` - would not "evaluate to True" be the same as `"not being False" for a boolean Series?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D sometimes I provide answers that guess at what a person might need.  I imagined a scenario where `'c3'` was not of `dtype==bool` but instead was `dtype=object`.  We could have nulls or other objects that aren't `True` or `False`.  This accounts for that.  Strictly speaking, and if we assume what the OP said is true, then you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 5):

Consider [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). This allows a chained operation, thereby avoiding referring to the dataframe by the name of its variable.

```
filtered_df = df.query('my_col')
```

This should return rows where `my_col` evaluates to true. To invert the results, use `query('~my_col'`) instead.

To do this in-place instead:

```
df.query('my_col', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is a `DataFrame` method. I am wondering if there is one for `Series`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `pipe`:

```py
df.pipe(lambda x: x[x['c3']])
```

It also works in a method chain like `query`, but also with a Series:

```py
df['c3'].pipe(lambda x: x[x])
```